# Calculate the neighbourhood inside or outside of a region

Tags: matlab, image-processing, nearest-neighbor, neighbours

I have a problem in MATLAB as follows:

Suppose I have a matrix like given below. What I want to do is calculate the average values of the pixels given in yellow. (ans is 108)
[image]

This will be calculated if the option given is **outside**.

On the other hand if the option is given as **inside**, then an operation as performed in the image.
[image]

**I want to write an algorithm to find out the average value either inside or outside the region marked with zeros depending on the option manually set. **

****4 neighbourhood** or **8 neighbourhood** ** may be considered. I want to compute this in MATLAB. Can you guys help me ?

Comment: hint, binarize the matrix and use `bwtraceboundary` to find the relevant pixels.

Comment: @natan can you be more specific please

Answer (score 5):

% Firstly, Create the images

```
FirstImage = [
108 113 121 129 128 124 117 101
114 76  60  110 98  74  121 109
114 62  52  105 85  59  121 116
110 59  54  104 0   0   0   115
104 55  54  104 0   0   0   113
96  48  51  105 0   0   0   113
94  60  69  115 0   0   0   110
99  108 122 130 135 0   0   109
];

SecondImage = [
0   0   0   0   0   0
138 137 137 137 0   0
138 127 129 135 138 0
132 97  99  133 135 0
134 108 110 137 137 0
141 140 140 140 139 0
138 138 138 140 0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0
];
```

% Make the image binary and invert it so that the zeros in the image are 1.
% This is to make it compatible with `bwtraceboundary`

```
im = FirstImage == 0 ;
```

% Find the object coordinates to match the requirements of `bwtraceboundary`

```
objectCoord = find(im); 
[startRow,startCol]  = ind2sub(size(im),objectCoord(1) );
```

% The `find()` function scans the matrix column-by-column 
% so we know that it will start in the top left corner and work 
 
% itself down, column-by-column. Therefore, some part of the boundary must 
% lie east of the first coordinate found. This is one way of finding 
% the starting coordinates

```
contour = bwtraceboundary(im,[startRow startCol],'E' );
```

% Mark the contour

```
contourimage = zeros(size(im));
contourind = sub2ind(size(contourimage),contour(:,1),contour(:,2))
contourimage(contourind) = 1;



contourimage =

  0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
  0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
  0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
  0     0     0     0     1     1     1     0
  0     0     0     0     1     0     1     0
  0     0     0     0     1     0     1     0
  0     0     0     0     1     0     1     0
  0     0     0     0     0     1     1     0
```

% Now, this will only detect the boundary of the object itself. 
% We are looking for the nearest non-zero values to the boundary.
% To get the nearest non-zero values,
% **apply dilution** to the countour image and 
% then multiply it element-wise with the original image.
% Calculate the mean of the non-zero values

% Perform dilution

```
mask = bwmorph(contourimage,'dilate')

mask =

 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1
 0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1
 0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1
 0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1
 0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1
 0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1
```

% Multiply the `mask` with the original image, element-wise.
% The object itself will then be zeroed out and the non-zero boundary will remain.

```
A=mask.*FirstImage

A =

 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0   105    85    59   121   116
 0     0     0   104     0     0     0   115
 0     0     0   104     0     0     0   113
 0     0     0   105     0     0     0   113
 0     0     0   115     0     0     0   110
 0     0     0   130   135     0     0   109
```

% Then calculate the average

```
mean(A(A>0))

ans =

108.6875
```

Comment: yep, that's about it... I've made you're code a bit more concise,  you got my +1

Comment: Hi I tried to run this but I am getting an error in bwtraceboundary coommand. It says "Error using bwtraceboundary
Expected input number 2, P, to be a vector.". I rechecked the code, it appears to be correct. Can anybody tell me why that error is being shown ?

Comment: It worked for me when I ran it though. Check that startRow and startCol are vectors of the same size. I haven't got Matlab here at the moment so I can't check it.

Comment: You could try this:
objectCoordinates = find(im>0); 
[startRow,startCol] = ind2sub( size(im) , objectCoordinates(1) );
contour = bwtraceboundary(im,[startRow startCol],'E' );

Answer (score 2):

Another solution:

use either:

```
BW = ~(FirstImage>0);
```

or:

```
BW = SecondImage>0;
```

then:

```
[B,L] = bwboundaries(BW,'noholes');
B=cell2mat(B);
m=zeros(size(BW));
m(sub2ind(size(BW),B(:,1),B(:,2)))=1
```